# Error de escritura (descriptor de archivo erróneo) al intentar escribir

Tags: c

Estoy intentando escribir la salida de un comando del bash de Linux en un fichero cuyo nombre indico mediante un array de strings.

```
if(isRedirection==1){
    fd = open(args[2], S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    dup2 (fd, 1);
    /* El descriptor 1, de la salida estándar, pasa a ser un duplicado de fd */
    write(  fd, "hola" , 50  );
    close (fd);
}

execvp(args[0],args);
```

`isRedirection` devuelve 1 cuando el array es del tipo `ls > salida.txt`, siendo "salida.txt" el fichero que tiene que abrir y escribir en él la salida del comando `ls`, la cual tengo entendido que es 1 (descriptor de archivos).

El comando `write` es sólo una prueba pero directamente el programa falla con el `open`. ¿Qué puede ser?

**Parámetros**:

- `args[0]` sería `ls`
- `args[1]` lo sustituyo por `NULL` en el método que me da `isRedirection`
- `args[2]` sería `salida.txt`

Answer (score 1):

La redirección te la está capturando la shell, así que en el programa que estas escribiendo argv[1] y argv[2] no existen.
Quiero decir, si tu ejecutable es `test` y ejecutas `./test > salida.txt` la shell ejecutará `./test` sin argumentos y la salida de este comando la redirigirá al fichero `salida.txt`

Puedes escapar la redirección ejecutando `./test \> salida.txt`

Respecto al código, parece que te has dejado las opening flags en el segundo argumento de `open`.

El siguiente fragmento `fd = open(args[2], S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);` debería quedar algo como `fd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);` para que cree el fichero si no existe, lo abra para lectura y escritura y escriba al final del fichero siempre.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Al grano:

```
open(args[2], S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
```

Eso establece atributos para un archivo que vas a crear, pero **no** indicas que quieres crearlo. Te falta un argumento:

```
open( args[2], O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
```

De todas formas, si `open( ... ) == -1`, en `errno` tendrás el código de error, que te indicará, mas o menos, cual es el fallo.

Comment: Tienes razón, me faltaba ese argumento para crear el fichero si no estaba ya creado pero sigo teniendo problemas con el dub cuando le indico que el descriptor de ficheros esté asignado con la salida estándar. Si pongo algo del tipo write(dub(fd,1) ... y el resto de los argumentos ) no me escribe nada de nada y me salta el error de descriptor de archivo erroneo igualmente. Me da la impresión de que no acabo de entender  lo del descriptor de archivos...

Comment: Tendrias que comprobar el retorno de dup2, algo como `if( dup2( ) == -1 ) fprintf( stderr, "%s", strerror( errno ) );`, incluyendo `<string.h>` y `<stdio.h>`. Seria muy util :-)

Comment: Rectifico, el dup2 no da ningún error( con perror("error") salta success, y con el condicional que me indicaste no llega a entrar pues no devuelve .1) , el error resulta de hacer el execvp(args[0],args), siendo que args[0] es "ls" y el error resultante es:" ls: error de escritura: descriptor de archivo erroneo."

Comment: Pues no lo veo. Si tu `write( fd, "hola" )` no te da error, tampoco debería de dartelo lo que ejecutes bajo  `execvp( )`, el hijo hereda stdout del padre, y se supone que el cierre de `fd` no deberia de afectar al otro. Prueba quitando el `close( fd )`, a ver que pasa.